# Mysql query to sum a column from a table where another two columns are unique when combined together

Tags: mysql, database

I have a Mysql table where it combines three tables. This table stores some statistics for each combination of the three foreign keys.

eg:

1)A **Files table**

columns-

```
id - primary key
name
number_of_lines_of_text - the stats field
```

2)A **Folders table** has a one to many relationship with files table

columns-

```
id - primary key
name
```

3)A **Folder_Groups table** has a many to many relationship with the folders table

columns-

```
id - primary key
name
```

Finally the combination table **ordered_file_stats**

columns-

```
folder_group_id - foreign key from 3 above(can repeat multiple times)
folder_id - foreign key from from 2 above(can repeat muliple times)
file_id - foreign key from 1 above, unique but only a subset of the records from 1
```

I need to select and sum the number_of_lines_of_text field of the **Files** table for each unique combination of the **folder_group_id** and the **folder_id** in the **ordered_file_stats** table.

Which may look like

```
folder_group_id   folder_id  file_id
     1                2         1
     1                2         2
     1                3         9
     2                1         7
     2                1         8
```

How do I write the select statement to obtain the stats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ofs.folder_group_id, ofs.folder_id, sum( Files.number_of_line_of_text) 
from ordered_file_stats ofs
join Files on Files.id = ofs.file_id
group by folder_group_id, folder_id
```